# How to use several apps in a vue project at the same time?

Tags: vue.js

If I have more than 2 apps in vue project. Can I communicate between several vue app?

```
<body>
 <div id="app1">
 </div>
 <div id="app2">
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Something like https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/ would probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is uncommon thing to have two apps in the same page. Instead you could use two components which will communicate using `vuex` for example.

But one of solutions I can think of is using `local storage`, since it's shared for the whole domain, not vue apps, so you can communicate in some manner.

Also, actually, I guess it's possible to share the same `vuex` store between two apps, since you can inject the same store for any component and a vue app is basically a one big component, like:

```
new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app1')

new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app2')
```

Haven't checked it though.

But I'd probably consider having one app anyway